# FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path build-impl.xml:1062

Tags: java

[image: 1]

I use NetBeans version 13 but it can't deploy the project. How can I fix `build-impl.xml:1062`?

I tried searching for build-impl.xml:1062 error but couldn't find it at all.

Comment: This post is lacking a [mcve] because it does not show the actual error that was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is not the error, you have to look into the server log as it is said in the error message. As far as I know net beans comes with GlasFish Server in general the logs are in /YOUR_GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/

If you need further help we need the serverlog.